# Trouble installing the EC2-steps-plugin

Tags: rundeck

I have installed the [EC2-steps plugin](https://github.com/rundeck-plugins/aws-ec2-steps), restarted rundeck, but I can't see the steps. Is there anything I'm missing here, installation or interface wise?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With this steps works:

1) Get the plugin with: `git clone https://github.com/rundeck-plugins/aws-ec2-steps`

2) Compress on .zip file with: `zip -r aws-ec2-steps.zip aws-ec2-step`

3) Now, move the zip file to `/var/lib/rundeck/libext` (DEB/RPM based installation) or `$RUNDECK_BASE/libext` (WAR based instllation).

4) Check the [new steps](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w68Y9.jpg) available.

Tip: Check the zip file permissions, make sure that the Rundeck user (or the user that launches Rundeck) can read the zip file.